# How to change the build email template in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How to change the default build email template in Gitlab CI.

From Below we can send email.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/project_services/builds_emails.html

But I have to change the default email template in Gitlab CI.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: Look at my answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240643/send-mail-to-commiter-after-gitlab-ci-stage/49984629#49984629 Maybe it's right for you.