# send mail to commiter after gitlab CI stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

in my .gitlab-ci.yml I have:

```
stages:
  - test # unit tests
  - proof # system tests
```

I want after each run send mail to committer how trigger run (in mail i want to have result of run). Could you tell me how should I do it or send me to same example?

Answer (score 1):

To [Bartłomiej Bartnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4284769/bart%C5%82omiej-bartnicki).
It seems [jaxxstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645002/jaxxstorm) talked about functionality in GitLab, which you can find by the path: your project -> Settings -> Integrations -> scroll down to the Project services and click by the "Emails on push" link and you will see the next settings page:[image]

By enabling this service, you will be able to receive e-mail notifications about the result status of your builds.

In the Recipients area, provide a list of e-mails separated by comma.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [build emails](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/project_services/builds_emails.html) service

Comment: The provided link is dead